# Powering USB hub using fast charger

Tags: usb, usb-hub

I'm working on a project where there will be 3 USB devices and a Qi transmitter that are hooked to a USB hub board. I just need USB High-Speed, not 3.0+. The 3 USB devices would consume total of ~1A.

I wanted to know that although theoretically possible, is there any issue with powering this hub via a USB fast charger. The rationale behind it is that USB fast chargers are easily available now and provide the required 5V/2A.

If yes, is there any advantage of using USB Type-C rather than microUSB?

Answer (score 1):

Provided the fast charger doesn't require some fancy software voodoo to get full power, I don't see why not, I've used USB chargers as power supplies before without issue. USB C is just a connector, it may have the capacity to handle more power, but that's only if the charger agrees and the hub can handle the extra power, at 1A, I'd stick with regular or micro USB - stick with whatever's most convenient.

Comment: 1A is for the three USB devices, then the hub will use ~100mA and then the rest for the Qi charger. I was thinking USB Type-C because it is rated for higher currents.

AFAIK, for fast charging, the data lines have to be shorted on the charger side, this will then tell the charging device to pull higher currents. In my case, the devices together will try to pull about 1.8A anyways.